# Setting innerHTML to nothing, not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
    clearConsole()
```

is the function that clears the console.
This is all the code-  http://michael.cheersgames.com/Tang/
use Ctrl+U to view the code.

```
    function clearConsole ()
    {
        console.innerHTML = '';
    }
```

My console-

```
    <div id="console">This is the console(text will appear below).<br /></div>
```

Comment: You've never hit F12? There's the `console` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML id's don't automagically become global vars in javascript - edit: apparently they do!!!

try

```
document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = '';
```

alternatively, use a different ID, so it doesn't "clash" with the console object

Comment: Thanks, it works. Why does it work then like that but not before? Oh OK then.

Comment: wow - so there was nothing wrong with the OP code!!! ... except for the choice of id :D

Comment: There was, but `console` is already defined, hence a HTML `id` won't  override it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the div element through its id then you can use

```
document.getElementById("console") // This is the div element.
```

Now you can clear the console using

```
document.getElementById("console").innerHTML ='' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that you need:

```
function clearConsole ()
{
    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: If you want to be upvoted more, explain why the new code works. +1